# How does one search for Haskell modules (not packages)?

Tags: haskell, package-managers

Does one know how search for a haskell module? For example, if were to type:

```
$> hadoodledoodledu Control.Concurrent.Threads
```

It would return:

```
concurrent-extras-0.3
concurrent-extras-0.4
bicameral-jacquard-loom-controller-4.2
```

It would be best if it could search my local cabal repo, but if that is impossible, that is okay.

Answer (score 4):

`$ ghc-pkg find-module Control.Concurrent.Threads`

If you enable documentation in cabal, you can find a list of all installed and documented modules in `~/.cabal/share/doc/index.html`

Comment: That just gave `$ ghc-pkg find-module Control.Concurrent.Threads
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
/home/theking/.ghc/i386-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d`

Comment: @PyRulez this means it couldn't be found in both configuration directories.

Comment: @PyRulez you could try `$ ghc-pkg find-module Control.Concurrent.* `.

Answer (score 1):

[hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0%3aControl.Concurrent.Thread) will do this but I'm not sure if you can configure it to work locally.